# My html code don't load FontAwesome icons, png image and google fonts

Tags: html, css

I started a project to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript and coded a full HTML page but my navigator doesn't load images, FontAwesome icons, and it doesn't apply my css file (tried on Brave and Microsoft Edge navigator).

I removed the most part of the code, I just left the CSS and header of my code - Any ideas of what is causing me trouble?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="/css/style.css">
        <link href="/css/normalize.css">
        <title>Booki</title>
        <nav>
            <a class="nav" href="#">Hébergement</a>
            <a class="nav" href="#">Activités</a>
        <nav>
        <a href="#"><img src="/assets/logo/Booki.png"></a>
    </head>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
I found how to display the path wasn't correct,i just need to remove the slash at the start of the path, and it works !

Comment: You can find a lot of question about this issue in SO, please make some research and check your path or browser console (it tells you where is the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `body` tag to render your content on the page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <title>Booki</title>
    </head>
<body>
       <nav>
            <a class="nav" href="#">Hébergement</a>
            <a class="nav" href="#">Activités</a>
        <nav>
        <a href="#"><img src="/assets/logo/Booki.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
```